# How to add style on javascript condition

Tags: javascript

I have a file with html and javascript. It show sum of values against arabic alphabets entered in text box. You can check sample by entering text like ا ب ج د ح و ز then it will show you sum of values against these numbers at bottom. Please tell me how can I make result text and result value as h1 and also a box behind result which is calculate by +sum; at end of script like this image.[link of image as i want to show result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgKY4.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta content="description" name="description">
  <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
  <meta content="Mashup templates have been developped by Orson.io team" name="author">

  <!-- Disable tap highlight on IE -->
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  
  <link href="./assets/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
  <link href="./assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon">

 

  <title>title</title>  

<link href="./main.a3f694c0.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>

<body>

 <!-- Add your content of header -->
<header>
  <nav class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle uarr collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-uarr">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html" title="">
          <img src="./assets/images/mashuptemplate.svg" class="navbar-logo-img" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-uarr">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="./index.html" title="" class="active"><h4>home</h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="./1.html" title=""><h4> 1</h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="./2.html" title=""><h4> 2 </h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="./3.html" title=""><h4> 3</h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="./4.html" title=""><h4> 4</h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="./5.html" title=""><h4> 5</h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="./6.html" title=""><h4><span style="color: #ff0000;">6</span></h4></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>


<div class="section-container border-section-container">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 section-container-spacer">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h2>textbox sample<span style="color: #ff0000;"></span></h2>
                        <h3> enter your text here:</h3>
                        <form name="chronform" action="">
<input id="chr" type="text" name="chrtext" onkeyup="tashvalue(form.rad[1].checked,document.getElementById('chr').value,form.calr[0].checked)" class="urdu" dir="rtl" style="height:3em;line-height:3em;;width:100%;font-size: 200%;">
<h3> <i>تشدید</i> :</h3>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad" VALUE="1" onClick="tashvalue(form.rad[1].checked,document.getElementById('chr').value,form.calr[0].checked)"> 1 time
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad" VALUE="2" onClick="tashvalue(form.rad[1].checked,document.getElementById('chr').value,form.calr[0].checked)" checked> 2 time
<h4>calender</h4>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="calr" VALUE="H" onClick="tashvalue(form.rad[1].checked,document.getElementById('chr').value,form.calr[0].checked)" checked> hijri
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="calr" VALUE="G" onClick="tashvalue(form.rad[1].checked,document.getElementById('chr').value,form.calr[0].checked)">georgen
</form>
<p></p>
<span id="hijri"></span><span id="isvia"></span><span id="isvib"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
function tashvalue(tashchoice,inputtext,calchoice) {
    if (tashchoice == false) {
        calcvalue(inputtext,calchoice);
         }
        else {removetashdeeds(inputtext,calchoice)}}
    
function removetashdeeds(origtext,cal1) {
    var tashdeedindex; 
    tashdeedindex = origtext.indexOf('\u0651');
   if (tashdeedindex > 0) {
        removetashdeeds((origtext.substring(0,(tashdeedindex)) + origtext.charAt((tashdeedindex - 1)) + origtext.substring(tashdeedindex + 1)),cal1);
   }
   else {
    calcvalue((origtext.substring(0,(tashdeedindex)) + origtext.charAt((tashdeedindex - 1)) + origtext.substring(tashdeedindex + 1)),cal1)}}

function calcvalue(text,cal2) {
    var x;
    var sum = 0;
    x = text;
//    sum += (66 * (x.match(/\uFDF2/g)||[]).length);  // allah = 66
//    sum += (786 * (x.match(/\uFDFD/g)||[]).length);  // bismillah ar-rahman ar-rahim = 786
    sum += (23 *(x.match(/\u0627|\u0622|\u0625/g)||[]).length);        // alif or alif hamza = 1
    sum += (52 * (x.match(/\u0628|\u067E/g)||[]).length);  // be or pe = 2
    sum += (62 * (x.match(/\u062C|\u0686/g)||[]).length);  // jeem or cheem = 3
    sum += (353 * (x.match(/\u062F|\u0688|\u0690/g)||[]).length);  // dal, Dal, or Dal with four points = 4
    sum += (34 * (x.match(/\u0647|\u06C1|\u06BE/g)||[]).length);  // he or he-final or DChe = 5
    sum += (234 * (x.match(/\u0648/g)||[]).length);  // wow = 6
    sum += (63 * (x.match(/\u0632|\u0698/g)||[]).length);  // ze or zhe = 7
    sum += (345 * (x.match(/\u062D/g)||[]).length);  // barihe = 8
    sum += (345 * (x.match(/\u0637/g)||[]).length);  // toy = 9
    sum += (345 * (x.match(/\u064A|\u06CC|\u06D2/g)||[]).length);  // chhotiye with or without dots or bari ye = 10
    sum += (345 * (x.match(/\u0643|\u06A9|\u06AF/g)||[]).length);  // kaf, kafvariant, or gaaf = 20
    sum += (345 * (x.match(/\u0644/g)||[]).length);  // lam = 30
    sum += (13 * (x.match(/\u0645/g)||[]).length);  // meem = 40   
    sum += (345 * (x.match(/\u0646|\u06BA/g)||[]).length);  // noon or noonghunna = 50     
    sum += (16 * (x.match(/\u0633/g)||[]).length);  // seen = 60
    sum += (137 * (x.match(/\u0639/g)||[]).length);  // ain = 70
    sum += (1342 * (x.match(/\u0641/g)||[]).length);  // fe = 80
    sum += (23 * (x.match(/\u0635/g)||[]).length);  // suad = 90
    sum += (62 * (x.match(/\u0642/g)||[]).length);  // qaf = 100
    sum += (1235 * (x.match(/\u0631|\u0691/g)||[]).length);  // Re or re = 200
    sum += (62 * (x.match(/\u0634/g)||[]).length);  // sheen = 300
    sum += (234 * (x.match(/\u062A|\u0679|\u067F/g)||[]).length);  // te, Te, or Te (4 dots) = 400
    sum += (234 * (x.match(/\u062B/g)||[]).length);  // se = 500
    sum += (62 * (x.match(/\u062E/g)||[]).length);  // khe = 600
    sum += (62 * (x.match(/\u0630/g)||[]).length);  // zal = 700
    sum += (62 * (x.match(/\u0636/g)||[]).length);  // zuad = 800
    sum += (62 * (x.match(/\u0638/g)||[]).length);  // zoy = 900
    sum += (23 * (x.match(/\u063A/g)||[]).length);  // ghain = 1000
//sum += (? * (x.match(/\u06D3/g)||[]).length);  // bariyehamza = ?
//  sum += (? * (x.match(/\u0621/g)||[]).length);  // hamzaalone = ?
//  sum += (? * (x.match(/\u0654/g)||[]).length);  // hamzaonhe = ?
//  sum += (? * (x.match(/\u0629/g)||[]).length);  // te marbuta = ?
//  sum += (? * (x.match(/\u0622/g)||[]).length);  // Alif madd = ?
//    sum += (? * (x.match(/\u06C2/g)||[]).length);  // hewhamza = ?
//sum += (7 * (x.match(/\u0649/g)||[]).length);  // alif maqsura = ?
//    sum += (? * (x.match(/\u06C3/g)||[]).length);  // temarbuta = ?
if (cal2 == true) {
    document.getElementById("hijri").innerHTML = " <h2>Value of your text is </h2>" +sum;

    }
    
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: here you output your result: `document.getElementById("hijri").innerHTML = " <h2>Value of your text is </h2>" +sum;` so you can add any format fo it as you wish i.e: `... = "<h1>Value of your text is " +sum+ "</h1>";` + add some styling etc.

Comment: document.getElementById("name").style.color = "blue"

Comment: Thank you very much @tarkh it works. But what about box behind value or just a value color change to red.

Comment: @tarkh can you please help me again for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989739/how-to-get-specific-value-from-web-page-and-put-it-on-other-html-pages-input-fi Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need? It's just matter of html/css styling

```js
const sum = 23671;

document.getElementById("hijri").innerHTML = '<h2><div class="resultbox">Value of your text is</div><div class="resultbox redbox">'+sum+'</div></h2>';
```

```css
#hijri {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Arial;
}
.resultbox {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
.redbox {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="hijri">
</div>
```

Comment: I am very thanks full to you @tarkh . You solved my problem. Best Regards